# Aplicação Spring MVC não faz o redirecionamento para página após login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, redirect

estou com um problema e gostaria de contar com a valiosa ajuda de vocês para resolvê-lo.

Após realizar o login na aplicação o usuário deve ser encaminhando para uma página de listagem de catálogos. O login em si está ok, porém, esse encaminhamento não acontece automaticamente: a página de listagem só é exibida quando informada a sua url diretamente no browser e pressionada a tecla ENTER. Fora isso, o usuário permanece na tela de login.

Seguem partes dos códigos desenvolvidos até aqui:

**SegurancaController.java**

```
//package e imports omitidos

@Controller
public class SegurancaController {

    @GetMapping("/entrar")
    public String realizarLogin(@AuthenticationPrincipal Usuario usuario) {
        if (usuario != null) {
            int usuarioId = (int) usuario.getId();

            return "redirect:/usuarios/" + usuarioId + "/catalogos/listar";

        } else
            return "entrar";
    }
}
```

**CatalogoController.java**

```
//package e imports omitidos

@Controller
@RequestMapping("usuarios/{usuarioId}/catalogos")
public class CatalogoController {
//...

    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public ModelAndView listar(@PathVariable("usuarioId") long usuarioId, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("catalogos", catalogoService.recuperarPorUsuario(usuarioId));
        model.addAttribute("usuarioId", usuarioId);

        return new ModelAndView("/catalogo/list", model);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
//package e imports omitidos

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http 
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/usuarios/cadastro", "/usuarios/salvar").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/entrar")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

Estou tentando resolver este problema há dias, sem sucesso!

Ficarei muito grato a todos que puderem ajudar. :)

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Na classe SecurityConfig, depois de .loginPage("/entrar"),vai colocar: `.defaultSuccessUrl("/listar", true)`

Comment: Olá @Mechior Feliz, desculpe pela demora em responder. Alguns problemas me impossibilitaram de responder antes. Obrigado pela sua ajuda! Isso resolve o meu problema, porém, eu não estou conseguindo pegar o id do usuário logado para passar como parte da url no defaultSuccessUrl("/usuarios/" + usuarioId + "/catalogos/listar", true). Tentei com SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()  dentro do método onde declarei defaultSuccessUrl(). Não obtive sucesso, pois recebo um NullPointerException quando vou subir o projeto. Poderia me ajudar? Desde já obrigado! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Usuario usuario = (Usuario)auth.getPrincipal();
int usuarioId = usuario.getId();
```

Deve funcionar,não esquece de marcar como respondida a questão,assim ajuda os amiguinhos

Comment: Olá, @Melchior Felix! Continua obtendo a NullPointerException: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`. :(